# LINQ to SQL mystery: Why does query include all fields in some cases but not others?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

This LINQ to SQL query

```
From g In Db.Context.Current.Groups
Select g.GroupID
```

generates this SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[GroupID]
FROM [dbo].[Groups] AS [t0]
```

But this query

```
From g In Db.Context.Current.Groups
Select g.GroupID, g.MemberCount
```

generates this SQL:

```
SELECT 
  [t0].[GroupID], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Description], ...
   -- 24 more fields - omitted for brevity 
FROM [dbo].[Groups] AS [t0]
```

`g.MemberCount` is a property of the `Group` class that returns an integer.

```
 Public ReadOnly Property MemberCount() As Integer
     Get
        Return (
            From cgx In KN.Db.Context.Current.ContactsGroupsXtabs
            Where cgx.GroupID = Me.GroupID
            Select cgx.ContactID
        ).Count()
     End Get
 End Property
```

I very much want to select only the fields I need. How can I persuade LINQ to SQL not to select all columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **first query**, LINQ to SQL knows it ***only*** needs to return a scalar value `GroupID` (or a `GroupID` array). So that's what it does: LINQ to SQL queries *only* that column in the database and returns only those value(s).

```
From g In Db.Context.Current.Groups
Select g.GroupID
```

In your **second query**, LINQ to SQL knows it needs to return a scalar (same as the first query), **plus the value returned by a property/method call on an actual entity instance**, a Group object.  So, to be able to call `MemberCount()` there must first be a Group object to call it on, right?  So LINQ to SQL must do a full entity fetch, and that's why it's querying all the columns.

```
From g In Db.Context.Current.Groups
Select g.GroupID, g.MemberCount 'property/method call on an entity
```

[Just theorizing here...] You might say, But `MemberCount()` doesn't need a full entity fetch, it doesn't need all that data - all it needs is `GroupID`.  And I would reply, How does LINQ to SQL know that?  How can LINQ to SQL know that your method `MemberCount()` *doesn't* rely on the data of other db-column-based properties?  It can't know that, so it must return the full object. [End theorizing.]

**Suggestion:** Join `ContactsGroupsXtabs` in your second query, group on `GroupID` and do a `Count()` on the group to get your value.  (I can see by your other SO questions and answers that you know how to do all that so I'll skip the example.)

Comment: Great answer, @shaunmartin. That makes a lot of sense.